# Getting/using output of CMD window of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I,m running a Java file from BeanShell Sampler in jmeter, I'm getting the output successful in cmd windows of jmeter. The output comprises of series of logger files,I need to extract only a specified string from the cmd window and use it for another sample

Comment: are you executing in windows or linux?

Comment: also give example of use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This java bean shell Command made the console out by j meter  that is std out to be written in a file

*System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\dir1\\dir2\\abc.out")),true));*

Make sure your path to file should have double backward slash

Answer (score 0):

Given you run your program using i.e. [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) you should be able to access its output via [Process.getInputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) method

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder('c:\\apps\\jmeter\\bin\\jmeter.bat', '-v').start()
String output = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(process.getInputStream(),'UTF-8')
log.info('My program output is:')
log.info(output)
```

Also I would recommend considering switching to [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as this way it will be much faster and easier:

```
def output = "jmeter.bat -v".execute().text
log.info('My program output is:')
log.info(output)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Program Output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer still i'm not getting the desired output

Comment: This is the Scenario I'm facing                                                                1. Environment is Windows                                                                    2,I  run a program in java using Jmeter(Beanshell Sampler and getting the output in cmd like Example"<FINE><10-30-2017  17:10:18><293><cr.abc><Firststring :RandomtUsUZhkeYVRn77VnwmGradnYs2N+uM71sey/tjpj9fWOSX4YzafUzNfN3Wco
hsI9b84gNzIc0Tp+QuLUtrZw==>
<FINE><10-30-2017  17:10:18><293><cr.abc2><Second string  : Randomlfhs;ofuh=>  I need to extract the First String and Second String in the next sampler